# Trouble authenticating and writing to database locally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, gcloud, google-cloud-spanner

I'm having trouble authenticating and writing data to a spanner database locally. All imports are up to date - google.cloud, google.auth2, etc. I have tried having someone else run this and it works fine, so the problem seems to be something on my end - something wrong or misconfigured on my computer, maybe where the credentials are stored or something?

Anyone have any ideas?

```
from google.cloud import spanner
from google.api_core.exceptions import GoogleAPICallError
from google.api_core.datetime_helpers import DatetimeWithNanoseconds
import datetime
from google.oauth2 import service_account


def write_to(database):
    record = [[
        1041613562310836275,
        'test_name'
    ]]

    columns = ("id", "name")
    
    insert_errors = []

    try:
        with database.batch() as batch:
            batch.insert_or_update(
                table = "guild",
                columns = columns,
                values = record,
            )
    except GoogleAPICallError as e:
        print(f'error: {e}')
        insert_errors.append(e.message)
        pass
    
    return insert_errors

if __name__ == "__main__":
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(r'path\to\a.json')
    instance_id = 'instance-name'
    database_id = 'database-name'
    spanner_client = spanner.Client(project='project-name', credentials=credentials)
    print(f'spanner creds: {spanner_client.credentials}')
    instance = spanner_client.instance(instance_id)
    database = instance.database(database_id)
    insert_errors = write_to(database)
```

some credential tests:
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(a_json)

> <google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials at 0x...>

spanner_client.credentials

> <google.auth.credentials.AnonymousCredentials at 0x...>

spanner_client.credentials.signer_email

> AttributeError: 'AnonymousCredentials' object has no attribute 'signer_email'

creds.signer_email

> '...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com'

spanner.Client().from_service_account_json(a_json).credentials

> <google.auth.credentials.AnonymousCredentials object at 0x...>

Comment: Hi hwhat, do you have the error message and stack trace?

Comment: @HailongWen There actually wasn't any error message, it just stopped at the ```with database.batch() as batch:``` part

Comment: OK, so it seems that the auth failed which yielded an AnonymousCredential. I suspect it may be related to the path of the credential file (e.g. absolute vs relative path). Another thing you can try is to use other ways listed in https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/1.7.0/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files to initialize the credential.

Comment: @hwhat did the issue get resolved?

Comment: @ManitGupta No, not yet.

Comment: I am having the same problem on Windows 10. Fresh environment and every script breaks with no errors.

Comment: It's worth noting that only the spanner library seems to be having trouble with the credentials on my machine @HailongWen. Every other google.cloud package authenticates just fine. Perhaps there's a version I could roll back to? Even when I get the credentials manually and verify they're valid, the python spanner client seems to ignore them when passing them in.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this is that you have accidentally set (or forgot to unset) the environment variable `SPANNER_EMULATOR_HOST`. If this environment variable has been set, the client library will try to connect to the emulator instead of Cloud Spanner. This will cause the client library to wait for a long time while trying to connect to the emulator (assuming that the emulator is not running on your machine). Unset the environment variable to fix this problem.

Note: This environment variable will only affect Cloud Spanner client libraries, which is why other Google Cloud product will work on the same machine. The script will also in most cases work on other machines, as they are unlikely to have this environment variable set.